# jQuery catch HTTP exception necessary?

Tags: jquery, try-catch, jsonp

Is it necessary to write the try catch block for the jquery ajax (jsonp).

The jQuery version is 1.4.x

There is a error function as the callback, but can not catch the 504 HTTP error.

Answer (score 0):

from **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

> You may want to specify the callback when you want to enable better
>   browser caching of GET requests. As of jQuery 1.5, you can also use a
>   function for this setting, in which case the value of jsonpCallback is
>   set to the return value of that function

as well as

> Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value
>   will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the
>   query string in the url. So {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result in
>   'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the
>   jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback"
>   string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In
>   this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting.

Comment: yes; i answered as much as i understand ur problem.. i may b wrong